# Movie about space with monsters with rock tentacles/spider legs

Tags: story-identification, movie, space

I remember watching a movie where there’s a group of spacefarers on a moon/desert like planet. They have gotten stuck on this planet. It’s pretty barren except for these tall rock pillars every now and then. They decide to spend the night in the middle of one such cluster of pillars.

They might’ve made a fire. Then all of a sudden the pillars explode/crumble to reveal that these are spider like legs and the ground they’re on is the mouth of one of these creatures.

This is all I remember from this movie and I always ask my friends but have not been able to find what it is.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you see this?  Was it live-action or animated?

Comment: Live action. Saw it on TV around 2015 (I am not sure on this date might be off by a few years)

Comment: Do you remember an overwhelmingly reddish colour to the scene with the monster?

Comment: Hi David, don’t think so. The movie had the Michael bay transformers type of filter to it. But again if there were other scenes with this filter I do not remember.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is ***[Starship Troopers 3: Marauder](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0844760/)*** (2008).

> Johnny Rico is called back into action to defeat the bugs.

A group of Federation soldiers are marooned on an alien planet and spend hours trekking along its surface. The area of the planet they're on is a sun-baked desert, with rocky protrusions sticking up from the ground here and there, as you described.

Around 55 minutes into the film, there's a scene where they camp out for the night, but don't encounter the spider-like creature you mentioned.

About ten minutes later into the runtime, though, there's another scene where they're attacked by a trio of alien bugs and a male soldier runs into a small circle of the rocky protrusions to prevent one of the bugs from being able to reach him. A female soldier tells him to get out of there, stating that the protrusions aren't rocks, but he ignores her warning. Then the protrusions start moving and are revealed to the rock-encrusted legs of a larger alien bug partially buried beneath the ground. The male soldier is stabbed by the legs and pulled underground seconds later.

You can view the latter scene in the video clip below.

Comment: This is it I believe! I remember this being a lot higher quality haha.

Comment: The first _Starship Troopers_ underperformed at the box office, so all the sequels were straight-to-video releases with much lower budgets.

Comment: Hopefully people will find this gem with this post haha

Comment: Are the guns like twice as big as the ones in the first movie? (This is the first I've ever heard of this sequel, so thanks for that!)

Comment: @Organic Marble - You can see the guns they're using in the video clip. They don't look significantly larger than the ones in the first film.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't remember them being so gigantic.

Comment: @Organic Marble - The guns in this film do look bigger from top to bottom, but shorter from front to back. I wouldn't have thought there's a big difference in overall mass. Here's a [clip from the first film](https://youtu.be/RtE3ue3hBhE?t=86) showing the guns they used there.

Comment: @LogicDictates These guns are comically big. The ones in the first movie are also big, but more proportional. No rifle stock on these ones, which is why it looks shorter back to front. If it had a stock it would probably be too long for her arms.

Answer (score 8):

It's a little recent, but could this be the 2020 film *[Monster Hunter](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6475714/)*?

Edited to add: This is a partial match as confirmed by OP.

In this movie a team of soldiers is missing and the search team sent out after them gets trapped in the desert by a storm, which pulls them into a portal transporting them to another world, where they find the wreckage of the vehicles from the team they are searching for.

They are chased by large sand-swimming monsters called "Diablos" into an area with large mud pillars inhabited by spider-like creatures that launch out and catch some of the team.

Youtube has the trailer, you can see the mud pillars at about 00:26:

Comment: Not this but I think I’ll watch this :D

Comment: @Harsh It's pretty mindless fun. I see you posted that the Starship Troopers was the correct one, while I was writing the answer. I might edit this to say "partial match".

Comment: I remember this film. It was surprisingly stupid and good fun to watch. No effort made on the plot just action.

Comment: Sounds good! Maybe it’ll help someone else